# Quel est le verbe associé au substantif « ablation » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, demande-de-mot

Je me retrouve parfois à écrire « lors de l’ablation de cet organe », mais je suis incapable de reformuler ce substantif en verbe : « lorsque le chirurgien ???? l’organe ». Du coup j’utilise « retirer » qui est moins précis.

Est-ce que ce verbe existe ? Et sinon, quel verbe utiliser ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Le verbe existe effectivement, il s'agit du verbe transitif *ablater*, qui se conjugue sur le modèle du verbe *chanter*. Il peut également être pronominal, dans quel cas il signifie subir une ablation.

Je ne suis pas spécialiste de la langue médicale, mais le Petit Robert donne quelques quasi-synonymes comme *exciser*, *amputer*, *effectuer une exérèse* et *pratiquer une -ectomie*.

Comment: Ce terme ne semble apparaître que dans des discussions méta-linguistiques. Google ne semble pas en trouver d'usage direct. Le TLFi ne note pas ce terme. Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait fournir quelques contextes authentiques ?

Comment: @GAMPUB « _Pour polir correctement un verre, il faut l’ablater par micro-usinage._ » (dans [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ablater)). Le pépin c'est qu'_ablater_ semble référer à produire une ablation mais c'est celle en géologie, et en sciences et tech., et peut-être pas directement celle en chirurgie, qu'on _pratique_, semble-t-il. Comparer avec [_abraser_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abraser) qui a une acception au TLFi. Merci.

Answer (score 4):

La formule la plus courante est la suivante : pratiquer l'ablation de...

Answer (score 2):

Le verbe "réséquer" me paraît adapté.
[http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/réséquer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9s%C3%A9quer)

Comment: _Enlever par [résection](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9section)_.

Comment: Non, une résection est un cas particulier d'ablation. Le verbe réséquer ne couvre pas tous les cas où l'on ablate, seulement ceux où l'ablation est une résection.

Answer (score 1):

Mon ‘Le Robert-Micro’ donne « On lui a **enlevé** les amygdales » comme exemple de l’usage du verbe « [enlever](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/enlever) » dans son sens de « supprimer ».

Le verbe anglais « [ablate](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/ablate) » se traduit comme « enlever » d’âpres ‘Reverso’ et dans sa rubrique « Context », « ablater » en Français se trouve comme verbe.

Personnellement, en anglais je dirais « extract an organ », mais mon ‘Le Robert’ a l’aire de parler de « extraire» pour seulement les « corps étrangers » (j’aurais cru que « [extraire](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=fr&langTo=en&q=extraire+une+dent&langTot=fr-en) » pourrait marcher avec « les dents », mais peut-être ‘Le Robert’ considère les dents comme « corps étrangers ») .

Comment: L'extraction dentaire c'est effectivement valable. Mais l'ablation n'est pas exactement équivalente; l'extraction impliquant une traction vers l'extérieur j'imagine, et d'un objet qui n'est pas exactement un organe... Merci.